# Minimising distance travelled back and forth inside a polygon

Tags: calculus, optimization

[image]

Consider the above image. Starting from $A$, we need to visit the segments $CD$, $AD$, $CD$ again, and finally arrive at $B$. What is the shortest distance we can travel to do this while moving in straight lines?

The solution presented cleverly bypassed the need to perform any rigorous calculus.
[image]

As can be seen in the second image, the polygon was mirrored and the path to be travelled was treated like a beam of light, reflecting off every surface to reach the point $B$ mirroring the point it was projected in the direction of, $B'''$. The path required is shown on the left hand side, and from the geometry the length can be calculated by $\sqrt{12^2+5^2}=13$.

My question is how would you reach this conclusion via a more conventional approach, using calculus. Minimising an expression for the length $L$ is difficult given the three points that need to be chosen together. How should this be approached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit more work it turns out the question is solvable by standard minimization.

There are three variable points, $P_1$ on $CD$, $P_2$ on $AD$ and $P_3$ on $CD$. Since we know the relationship between the $x$ and $y$ values of these points as they all lie on straight lines, we can represent these points with three variables. Let $P_1 = (x,-x+6)$, $P_2 = (y,0)$ and $P_3 = (z,-z+6)$.

[image]

Our restrictions are therefore
$$1\leq x\leq6$$
$$0\leq y\leq6$$
$$1\leq z\leq6$$

That gives total distance travelled $$L = \sqrt{(0-x)^2+(0-(-x+6))^2} + \sqrt{(y-x)^2+(0-(-x+6))^2} + \sqrt{(z-y)^2+(-z+6-(0))^2} + \sqrt{(0-z)^2 + (5-(-z+6))^2}$$

Taking partial derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = \frac{4x-12}{2\sqrt{2x^2-12x+36}} + \frac{4x-2y-12}{2\sqrt{2x^2+y^2-2xy-12x+36}} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = \frac{2x-2y}{2\sqrt{2x^2+y^2-2xy-12x+36}} + \frac{-2z+2y}{2\sqrt{2z^2-12z-2zy+y^2+36}} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial z} = \frac{4z-12-2y}{2\sqrt{2z^2-12z-2zy+y^2+36}} + \frac{4z-2}{2\sqrt{2z^2-2z+1}}= 0$$

These are solvable via some lengthy but simple algebra to yield a system of equations.

$$x=\frac{36}{-y+12}$$
$$y=\frac{2xz-6x-6z}{x+z-12}$$
$$z=\frac{6}{7-y}$$

Substituting expressions for $x$ and $z$ in terms of $y$

$$y = \frac{2[\frac{36}{-y+12}][\frac{6}{7-y}]-6[\frac{36}{-y+12}]-6[\frac{6}{7-y}]}{[\frac{36}{-y+12}]+[\frac{6}{7-y}]-12}$$

Which yields the very workable cubic in terms of $y$

$$y^3-\frac{31}{2}y^2 + 78y - 126 = 0$$

Which yields solutions $y = 6$, $y=\frac{7}{2}$, of which $y=6$ is an invalid solution.
Substituting into the simultaneous equations from earlier, we get $x=\frac{72}{17}$, $z=\frac{12}{7}$ and of course we know $y=\frac{7}{2}$.

Thus

$$L = \sqrt{(\frac{72}{17})^2+(0-(-\frac{72}{17}+6))^2} + \sqrt{(\frac{7}{2}-\frac{72}{17})^2+(0-(-\frac{72}{17}+6))^2} + \sqrt{(\frac{12}{7}-\frac{7}{2})^2+(-\frac{12}{7}+6-(0))^2} + \sqrt{(0-\frac{12}{7})^2 + (5-(-\frac{12}{7}+6))^2} = 13$$

As required. There are definitely faster ways of doing it. Lagrange multipliers might do the trick but ultimately lead to the same solution the same way. Another (non calculus) approach is to angle a line from $A$ so it is pointed at the horizontal reflection of the polygon, at $B'''$. Since the angle of incidence equals the angle of reflection, you could take the difference in the angle of the lines $AB'''$ and  the perpendicular to $CD$. A new line could be constructed with the same difference in angle after reflection, set to intersect $AD$. Of course, by choosing to use this method you are not aiming to find just the length $L=\sqrt{(2*6)^2+5^2} = 13$, but instead are aiming to obtain the coordinates of $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$. [image]